# Git "best practices" for a "base" for all my projects

Tags: git, branching-and-merging

I'm a many-years advanced git user. Recently I find myself with the following problem, and I cannot seem to find a description / solution online, making me think that maybe I'm trying to solve the problem in the wrong way:

I have 20 python repos. There is a lot of stuff that I seem to duplicate between repos (`mypy.ini` files, flake8 config files, files that run all tests in docker containers after doing some sanity checks, `setup.py` files). These files are 90% the same between all repos, with only minor (intended) changes; and quite some changes that happened because I improved some stuff in 1 repo, and then didn't have time to move the changes over to all other repos.

I recently took some time to clean everything up, and now I have 1 "base" set of files, that should exist in all repos (and all new repos). I could copy these out to all repos, but it would mean that for every small improvement I need to manually copy this over to all other repos (and check that the file was not changed in that repo, or else merge the changes).

The solution I came up with:

I made a repo `base`; here I commit these files.

In every repo, I merge in base:

```
git remote add base git@github.com/XXXX/base.git
git config remote.base.pushurl "you really didn't want to do that"  # make sure one cannot accidentally push to base
git fetch base
git merge base/master --allow-unrelated-histories -m "merging base" --no-fast-forward
git push
```

Now later when I update something in base, I can merge it to echo of the repos at my own leisure (let's say, when I'm working on that repo anyways), by doing

```
git fetch base
git merge base/master
git push
```

It will (should) do what git is good at: check what has changed in base since the last merge, see if any of the local changes would result in conflicts, merge the whole thing and only bother me if there's something I need to provide input on (merge conflict).

### Now here are the things bothering me in this approach

- Maybe I'm just not looking well enough, but I cannot find anyone describing this strategy online, making me thing that probably there is some reason why it should not be used. *What am I missing?*
- I have some problems with git "collapsing the merge". What I mean by this; after merging (and some commits and remerging), things should look like this:

```
master       -----*---*---*---*---*---*----*----*----*-----*---------*----*----*----*---*
                             /            /                         /
base/master  --*--------*---------------*---------------*-----*---*---------*
```

(so in this situation, base/master is merged 3 times into master, the latest commit merge not yet merged)

However what I get (sometimes; not 100% sure when yet) is:

```
master       -----*---*---*---*---*---*----*----*----*-----*---------*----*----*----*---*

base/master  --*--------*---------------*---------------*-----*---*---------*
```

The changes are in master, however not as merges from base/master. This means that next time I try to do a merge, the system complains that there is no shared history for the 2 branches. *Now my hunch is, that this is because I don't have the `--no-fast-forward` in the `git merge` command (after the initial merge). Is this hunch correct? If so, that's an easy fix for now, but how do I avoid completely messing up my history if next time I forget to add `--no-fast-forward`?*

### Other approaches I considered

- **Using git submodules / git subtrees**: The problem is that many of the files I want to share, are supposed to be root dir. I guess I could try to make symlinks to all of them, but that still means some manual work per project.
- **Using pypi packages**: Same issue that things need to be in the root dir. Also, some of the things I have in the shared directory are especially helpers for installing pypi stuff.

Comment: If you have to run `git merge --allow-unrelated-histories` in the first place, Git can't do a fast-forward so you should get a true merge. You might work on the "sometimes" part to pin down what's going on here, because your strategy as outlined should be fine. Perhaps you're not always doing a merge that requires the `--allow-unrelated-histories` option, i.e., sometimes you start with a `master` commit that *is* a `base/master` commit?